# laravel post forms route error i think

Tags: php, laravel-5

Hi there i'm trying to retrieve some text from my html form in laravel. I set up my routes,my controller and my form. Please can you tell me where i'm mistaking???

So this is my routes:

```
Route::get('/','MainController@index')->name('main');

Route::post('/data/store', 'PostController@store')->name('save_data');
```

This is my PostController

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use Illuminate\Http\Request;

use App\Post;
use App\Http\Controllers\PostController;

class PostController extends Controller
{
    public function store(Request $request){
        $data = $request->all();
        var_dump($data);
        exit;
    }
}
```

And my form:

```
<form action{{ route('save_data') }} method="POST">
        <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="text" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter text...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value ="Save post">Send text</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: Can you please tell us what kind of error you get?

Comment: http exception.

Comment: whoops already solved, i just need to point to right path in route.

Answer (score 0):

You should also pass csrf_field in order for this to work.

```
<form action{{ route('save_data') }} method="POST">
        {{ csrf_field() }}
        <div class="form-group-lg">
            <label for="exampleInputEmail1">Text</label>
            <input type="text" class="form-control"  name="text" aria-describedby="emailHelp" placeholder="Enter text...">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value ="Save post">Send text</button>
    </form>
```

Comment: i have another file where i put my @csrf token :)